# convert PDF to HTML(one paragraph in each <span>tag)

Tags: python, html, file, pdf, converters

I'm junior data scientist with 3 months experiences.
Now, I'm going to convert the pdf file to html file.
using several convert API, I achieved converting.
But, current html represent one word in each `<span>`.
I want to html to represent one paragraph in each `<span>` at least.

```
import pdfcrowd
import sys

try:
    # create the API client instance
    client = pdfcrowd.PdfToHtmlClient('demo', 'ce544b6ea52a5621fb9d55f8b542d14d')

    # run the conversion and write the result to a file
    client.convertFileToFile('./111.pdf', 'logo.html')
    
except pdfcrowd.Error as why:
    sys.stderr.write('Pdfcrowd Error: {}\n'.format(why))
    raise
```

Comment: Please [check the markdown help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You could look at the documentation to see if you can tweak the pdfcrowd. Alternatively use another parser that understands, or post-process the HTML. Something like this: https://imgur.com/a/tUQfiz2